# What algorithm should I use to solve this optimization problem?

Tags: algorithms

Suppose that m different n-length row vectors $x_1,...x_{m}$ ($m > n$) are given. For each permutation of 1:m, $i_1,...i_m$, I can build a m by n matrix $X$ = bind_rows($x_{i_1},...,x_{i_m}$). Now I want to maximize the sum of diagonal elements of matrix $T=X_{1,1}+X_{2,2}+...+X_{n,n}$. If m and n are small, I can list all of the permutations and get the best one. But if $m$ and $n$ are greater than 15, for example, $m = 17, n = 15$, what kind of algorithm should I use?

Comment: If m > n, how are we summing up to the (m,m) term of X?  Each row has only n columns, right?

Comment: You are right, should be $X_{n,n}$. Sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of this as an [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem): you are looking for a maximal-weight matching in the bipartite graph where one part consists of the vectors $x_1, \ldots, x_m$, the other the positions $1,\ldots, n$, and edge $(x_i, j)$ has weight $(x_i)_j$.  Efficient algorithms are available.

Comment: The definition of the assignment problem in the link provided states that the goal is to find a bijection between sets of equal size (that minimizes the cost function).  The two sets here would be of size m and n?  Can the same linear programming technique then be applied?  It seems to me that something would need to change in the constraints which state that "each vertex is adjacent to exactly one edge in the matching", since m minus n of the x vectors must be excluded from the sum.

Comment: In the linear programming formulation, if $|A| < |T|$ you change the constraints $\sum_{i \in A} x_{ij} =1$ to $\sum_{i \in A} x_{ij} \le 1$.